# Combining three URL components into a single URL

Tags: python, url

I am trying to write a function combine three components of a URL: a protocol, location, and resource, into a single URL.

I have the following code, and it works only partially, returning a URL with only the protocol and resource components, but not the location component.

Code:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os
def buildURL(protocol, location, resource):
    return urllib.parse.urljoin(protocol, os.path.join(location, 
    resource))

Example: buildURL('http://', 'httpbin.org', '/get')
```

This returns `http:///get`. I a trying to debug this to also allow for the location parameter to be in the URL. It should be returning `http://httpbin.org/get`.

How can I build a URL successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you put `/get` in the `os.path.join`. you should call it like `buildURL('http://', 'httpbin.org', 'get')`. `os.path.join` will treat `/` as an absolute path that will be hooked from the root of the base location, which is the first parameter of the `join` function: `location`

Comment: Thank You. It does work without the / in front of get. However, is there a way to write code that will still combine the three even though the third parameter is /get? I'm trying to write a function that will work even if there is a / in front of the text. Thank You.

Comment: @JakePrice `resource[1:] if resource[0] == '/' else resource`

Comment: @JakePrice I think Chris's answer is better.

Comment: Ok, I thought this worked but it unfortunately did not. I am trying to work with @Chris 's answer

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `os.path` here at all. That module is for *filesystem* paths, e.g. to deal with things like `/usr/bin/bash` and `C:\Documents and Settings\User\`.

It's not for building URLs. They aren't affected by the user's host OS.

Instead, use [`urlunparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunparse) or [`urlunsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunsplit) from `urllib.parse`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlunparse

urlunparse(('https', 'httpbin.org', '/get', None, None, None))
# 'https://httpbin.org/get'
```

Comment: Hi There, thank you for your help, this helps a lot. However, it doesn't work when the first argument is 'http://' instead of just 'https'. Is there a way to adjust this where it could still work when the first parameter already has the :// attached on it? For example, for this function:                                                                                         from urllib.parse import urlunparse
def buildURL(protocol, location, resource):
    return urlunparse((protocol, location, resource, None, None, None))
buildURL('http://', 'httpbin.org', '/get') to still work

Comment: The best way is just to pass in the `https` part. Why do you want to include `://` in your input? Is it coming from somewhere else? (The module follows [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986.html), where the "scheme" is something like `https` and it is separated from the "authority" by `://`.)

Comment: Hello,I'm just trying to write a function that works for any of the following first arguments being entered: 'http://', 'http', and 'https'. I was trying to see how the function could still be workable with 'http://' as the first argument in the function. Thank You.

Comment: Your suggestion works really well, I just wanted to see if there was way to adjust it so 'http://' could also work with it. Maybe an if statement?

Comment: @JakePrice, feel free to check that argument, e.g. with [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=endswith#str.endswith) and modify it if necessary. You could also use a regular expression, strip whitespace, normalize case, etc. if you want. The main point is that `os.path` isn't the right module to use for building URLs, and that there are two functions right in `urllib.parse` that are a better fit.

Comment: How would i go about using a regular expression to solve this issue of the argument 'http://' not working? I would appreciate a suggestion, but if not, I'd understand. Thank You.

Comment: @JakePrice, I feel like we're getting off-topic here, and regular expressions add possibly unnecessary complexity and computation. Whether it's worth doing really depends on your specific use case. But if you match a regular expression like `[a-z][a-z+.-]*` (see the RFC) against your input you should be able to use the  whole match to get the scheme, or you could have a more complex pattern and use capture groups. I only used lowercase letters there so you'll probably want to lowercase your input before you use it. Or, to preserve case, add uppercase letters to the regex.